# show html child elements with same class name as the parent element and hide other elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<div class="element-2">
  <div class="element-1">
    <p>div 1</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="element-2">
    <p>div 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

i want the parent div to only show child divs with similar class name and hide the mismatch class name child divs.

Comment: What is your use case for this? As my answer shows, this approach is error-prone and probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot state *has same class* in CSS syntax. What you can do is explicitly list them:

```css
div.element-2 > div:not(.element-2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="element-2">
  <div class="element-1">
    <p>div 1</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="element-2">
    <p>div 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that this might have unintended side effects:

```css
div.element-2 > div:not(.element-2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="element-2">
  <div class="element-1">
    <p>div 1</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="element-2">
    <p>div 2</p>
    <div>This is also hidden</div>
  </div>
</div>
```